# MongoDB updates entire collection with the same document

Tags: python, mongodb

I have some documents in my MongoDB collection, they look like this:

```
number: first
value: 1

number: two
value: 2

number: three
value: 3
```

I want to update all the documents in the collection so that the `value` field of each document is changed to a random number, like this:

```
number: first
value: 4747

number: two
value: 1024

number: three
value: 102
```

I tried the following code:

```
cursor = db.mycol.find()

for record in cursor:
    record = db.mycol.raplace_many({}, {"value": random.randrange(10000)})
```

The problem with this is that instead of updating each document with a new random value, it updates all of them with the same random value, like this:

```
number: first
value: 1024

number: two
value: 1024

number: three
value: 1024
```

Why is this happening? I tried the same thing, but with `update_many` instead of replace, but the output is the same. Every advice is appreciated!

On the other hand, if i try to insert the value using `insert_one` the output will be the expected, so each field will have a different random value.

Comment: *Why* this is happening: because you're only generating one random value in Python which you're passing to the Mongo API. You need to generate the value within Mongo, if anything.

Comment: Ok! But then, why does it work when i use insert instead of update?

Comment: If you do `insert_one`? Well, that inserts *one* document. If you do that in a loop and you generate another random value every time, then you get many documents with a different value.

Comment: Isn't this what i'm already doing? I mean, for each record it should generate a random number

Comment: `x = randrange(10000)` `print(x)` `replace_many(..., {'value': x})` – This is what you're doing. There's only one `x`. Its value doesn't change.

Comment: The comments are not correct. You _do_ generate a random value for each document, but you are overwriting all documents every time you do it: `replace_many({}, ...` - the `{}` means match _all_ documents. You would need to do: `replace_many({'_id': record['_id']}, ...` (and maybe use `replace_one`).

Answer (score 1):

The following code can do the trick:

```
//Fetching the array of object IDs from the collection.
var objectIDs= db.collection.distinct("_id");

// Iterating over the array and updating the 'value' correspond to each object ID with a random value. Since there is a default index on object ID, the operation would be fast.
objectIDs.forEach(id=>{
    db.collection.update(
        {
            "_id":id
        },
        {
            $set:{
                "value": Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
            }
        }
    )   
});
```

**Before update:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3ab4"), "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3ab5"), "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3ab6"), "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3ab7"), "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3ab8"), "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3ab9"), "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3aba"), "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3abb"), "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3abc"), "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3abd"), "value" : 1 }
```

**After update:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3ab4"), "value" : 3538 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3ab5"), "value" : 9678 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3ab6"), "value" : 8325 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3ab7"), "value" : 2986 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3ab8"), "value" : 6159 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3ab9"), "value" : 4564 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3aba"), "value" : 7185 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3abb"), "value" : 2585 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3abc"), "value" : 7073 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8774e19f062d4c422b3abd"), "value" : 4094 }
```